# what is the order of execution of more than one handler (function call) on single event triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

in angular, if i have three method to exeute when click event triggered.follwing is the code for better understanding:

```
<div ng-click="handler1();handler2();handler3()" class="btn btn-info">submit</div>
```

i am confused to order of execution of these handler.i want to know  in which order this method or handler will execute. assume that `handler2()` has ajax call.

**Note** - i observed that 2nd handler has ajax call.so it is not executing after one another.

Comment: They will execute in natural order of course. However if you are saying there are AJAX request in the second handler, then you need to understand that asynchronous operations return immediately, but their response is available after some delay.

Comment: its order is one by one as you defined..in your case handler1() > handler2() > handler3()...but handler3() will not wait for completing ajax request if suppose handler2() has..Means, its all asynchronously called

Answer (score 0):

To restate what was already suggested in the comments:

In order of execution:

1. handler2()
2. handler1()
3. handler3()